# Assign nil value to double in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iOS iPhone app I have this method:

```
-(id)initWithLocationName:(NSString *)locatNm latitude:(double)lati longitude:(double)longi xCoord:(double)xco yCoord:(double)yco;
```

In this method I need to assign `nil` value to `xCoord` & `yCoord`.

How can I assign `nil` to `double`?

Comment: xCoord & yCoord arn't pointers so you can't assing nil to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nil is just 0. Setting them to 0 will do the same thing that setting them to nil would do.

Answer (score 13):

`nil` is for Objective-C objects, and `double` is a primitive data type (i.e., it isn’t an Objective-C object), hence you cannot assign `nil` to a `double` variable.

If `0.0` is not an option to represent the absence of value, you can use `NAN` and `isnan` instead. For instance:

```
#include <math.h>

double x = 0.0;
double y = NAN;

if (isnan(x)) NSLog(@"x is not a number"); // this won't be logged
if (isnan(y)) NSLog(@"y is not a number"); // this will be logged
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a double value of nil.  It's not a reference type, it's a primitive.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Aside:

If you weren't trying to use it in this method, you could utilize `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f]` and as any pointer, `NSNumber *number = nil;` is perfectly valid.  But it won't work in this scenario, since the method requires `double`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only assign `nil` to pointer types. You can assign 0.0 to a `double` however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign nil to pointers. Instead of using nil, I would use a special value, usually -1. If you really need to use nil, you'll need to wrap the double in a NSNumber.

Comment: -1 would work very poorly with a `double`. What the OP needs to do is rethink his API or his need for passing a nil.

Comment: Using `-1`  to model `nil` works fine if only positive values are valid.